# use function in stored procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql, function, select, stored-procedures, conditional-statements

I have created a stored procedure in mysql:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `get_PublicationsByDate`(IN _DateS DATE, IN _DateF DATE)
BEGIN

    SELECT 
        CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM filed_date), " Q", EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM filed_date)) AS date, 
        count(CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM filed_date), " Q", EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM filed_date))) AS count
    FROM 
        applications
    WHERE
        filed_date between _DateS and _DateF
    GROUP BY
        CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM filed_date), " Q", EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM filed_date))
    ORDER BY
        CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM filed_date), " Q", EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM filed_date));

END
```

I want to replace the long code

```
CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM filed_date), " Q", EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM filed_date))
```

of a function call (еxample in pseudo C ++ for convenience):

```
char* func(char* date)
{
return CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date), " Q", EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM date))
}
```

Because these long expressions may vary depending on the external parameter (pseudo code):

```
DECLARE F FUNCTION;

IF (_Type = 0)
    SET F = Func1;
ELSE
    SET F = Func2;
END IF;

SELECT F(filed_date), count(F(filed_date))...
```

**How in mysql I create it?**

Comment: `create function`...?

Comment: Shadow, maybe, but how use this function?
it is a global function or local in stored procedure?

Comment: You cannot declare a function within a stored procedure in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

CREATE FUNCTION decide my problem.

it is a pity that the function of the external

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `prepare_ScaleCondition`(_Scale VARCHAR(16), _Date DATE) RETURNS varchar(64) CHARSET utf8
BEGIN
    DECLARE _ScaleCondition VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM _Date);

    CASE _Scale
        WHEN 'quarter' THEN SET _ScaleCondition = CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM _Date), ' Q', EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM _Date));
        WHEN 'year' THEN SET _ScaleCondition = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM _Date);
        WHEN 'month' THEN SET _ScaleCondition = CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM _Date), ' M', EXTRACT(MONTH FROM _Date));
        WHEN 'week' THEN SET _ScaleCondition = CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM _Date), ' W', EXTRACT(WEEK FROM _Date));
    END CASE;

    RETURN _ScaleCondition;
END

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `get_PublicationsByDate`(IN _DateS DATE, IN _DateF DATE)
BEGIN

    SELECT 
        prepare_ScaleCondition(filed_date) AS date, 
        count(prepare_ScaleCondition(filed_date)) AS count
    FROM 
        applications
    WHERE
        filed_date between _DateS and _DateF
    GROUP BY
        prepare_ScaleCondition(filed_date)
    ORDER BY
        prepare_ScaleCondition(filed_date);

END
```